# mp3 and pdf file uploads not working like jpg

Tags: php, file-upload

this is my upload.php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    //File properties
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    //Work out the file extension
    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    $allowed = array('txt', 'jpg', 'mp3', 'pdf');

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)){
        if($file_error == 0){
            if($file_size <= 10000000){

                $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                $file_destination = 'uploads/' . $file_name_new;

                if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)){
                    echo $file_destination;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

what i don't understand is why it doesn't let me upload mp3 and pdf files, it seems to work perfectly with jpg files, but when i try and upload a sound or acrobat file it just doesn't seem to work, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: also i DID check the php config file and set the maximum file size to 10mb so the size of the file should not be an issue

Comment: so when i upload a jpg file it echos out the file_destination which is basically just the uniqid, however that does not happen with the mp3 files (i feel like this is a clue to my problem but i still can't figure out the actual reason)

Comment: A couple notes, you shouldn't use extension to determine file type (since they can be incorrect / changed) and should generally rely on MIME detection. That said, if your file is larger than 10MB won't `if($file_size <= 10000000){` not match (and prevent the rest from running)?

Comment: Also, what is the value of `$file_error` when you upload an mp3?

Comment: honestly i copied most of this code from a tutorial about how to upload files, i went over it a couple of times, and technically understand how it works, but im still a pretty novice php programmer so... plain and simple i need help figuring out how to upload sound files

Comment: Ah, so what's the value of `$file_error` when you try and upload an MP3? And how large (filesize) is the MP3 you're uploading?

Comment: the value of $file_error is 1 (so it encounters an error). for now i am uploading pretty small mp3 files (roughly 2 or 3mb) however this is just for testing purposes while i am just trying to get the code to work. my overall plan is to upload very large sound files (one or more hundred mbs), compress them (so i can efficiently store them on a server) and then uncompress them whenever a user decides to download them (but that's out of scope of what im currently trying to get working)

Comment: `$file_ext = explode()` returns an array. `in_array($file_ext, $allowed)` searches for this array in $allowed. Is it really what you want? Or do you want to search only the last `$file_ext` element (assuming the extension is the LAST group of chars following a dot) in `$allowed`

Comment: What values does `phpinfo()` return for `post_max_size`,  `upload_max_filesize` and `memory_limit`? They all need to be >= 10M.